# PHP: Detect unique & duplicates values in 2 multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

So I searched around, but I couldn't find a good answer to my question, so here goes. I'm pulling some data through json, which gets updated every hour.

I want to take this data and save it to my database and categorize the data as "new", "active" & "old"

I have saved a json feed in my database that looks like this when I pull it from the database:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2040154277 [3] => 74708 [4] => a )
[1] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2040088680 [3] => 42973 [4] => b ) 
[2] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2038497801 [3] => 21308 [4] => c ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2040404080 [3] => 82800 [4] => d ) 
[4] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2039988402 [3] => 74703 [4] => e ) 
[5] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2038753364 [3] => 82800 [4] => f ) 
[6] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2040065624 [3] => 54443 [4] => g ) 
[7] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2040153539 [3] => 82800 [4] => h )
)
```

I have made it a little bit more readable by adding letters to [4], but the only unique identifier is the number in [2].

Anyway, this data reflects what data was current 1h ago, so when the new feed comes in:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2040123457 [3] => 74708 [4] => aa )
[0] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2040154277 [3] => 74708 [4] => a )
[1] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2040088680 [3] => 42973 [4] => b ) 
[3] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2040404080 [3] => 82800 [4] => d ) 
[4] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2039988402 [3] => 74703 [4] => e ) 
[5] => Array ( [0] => Blood [1] => all [2] => 2038753364 [3] => 82800 [4] => f ) 
)
```

We notice that [4] c, g & h have expired, but also that [4] aa is new.

Using the old & new array, how can I identify which ones are new, active & old for a simple insert/update in my sql in a fairly efficient way as the multidimensional array can very well contain 50-60k arrays.

Is there a good way to solve this?

Comment: Did you try it yourself?

Comment: Are you limited to PHP and mysql for this?

Comment: Why do you care which are old active and new? What makes something new vs. active vs. old? Why are you passing around 50-60K arrays in a single array?  It seems likely that there are much more efficient ways to do this. For starters, how about use the value at index 2 in the subarrays as a lookup key?

Comment: Thanks for all your replies guys:

1. I tried to create 2 loops that goes through all the values, but doing that for 50k * 60k arrays with some 25 values each was way to inefficiant.

2. Yes.

3. I need to flag old/active for different uses in the db and I can't predict when something will expire.

I need to know what is new in order to create an Insert query rather than an update query.

I am not creating the array, it's simply the way the json (over which I have no control) is formatted.

I tried doing that using array_search, but that was quite sluggish.